# Can you guarantee different lifetime behavior based on whether a return value is used?

Tags: c++, move, rvalue, ownership

Assume we have some kind of `subscriber` object that is utilizing RAII to clean itself up on destruction.

We have code that is documented to claim the following:

> **1.** If you capture the return type, the subscriber will live as long as the value you captured lives.
>
> **2.** If you don't capture the return type, the subscriber will live as long as the object whose method you called to create the subscriber.

To clarify, the code looks like this:

```
template <class... Args>
id &&connect_subscriber(Args &&... args)
{
    auto id = connect_subscriber_with_id(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(subscriber_id_mutex_);
        subscriber_ids_.push_back(std::move(id));
        return std::move(subscriber_ids_.back());
    }
}
```

And the documentation is:

```
/// If the resulting `subscriber_id` is assigned storage at the call
/// site, then the subscription will be managed exclusively by the caller.
/// This means that until the identifier is either destroyed or
/// `disconnect_subscriber()` is called with it, the subscription will stay
/// active.
///
/// Conversely, if the `subscriber_id` is not assigned storage at
/// the call site, it will be managed internally inside the task and the
/// subscription will persist for the life-time of the task.
```

Can we guarantee that ownership will be transferred based on whether the return type is captured?

Comment: A) "capture the return type" doesn't make sense. You can't "capture types". B) If you capture "auto&& x = connect_subscriber();", you also don't get RAII the way you claim with your present setup.

Comment: What terminology do I use to distinguish between `x = foo();` and `/* */ foo();`?  How about: "If you assign the return value of a function call"?

Comment: How about "if you move from the return value"?

Comment: I'm not really clear on the question. Your code returns a reference to an element of the `subscriber_ids_` container.  The calling code can choose what to do with the referred-to object, including whether or not to move out of it.

Comment: There's no difference in object lifetime based on what the caller does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggle a little bit with the terminology used by you, but if I got the questioin right, I think, what is meant is something along the following quick and dirty mce inspired by your code example.

If you do not provide storage for the return value of connect_subscriber the std::move will not succeed and the id will remain in subscriber_ids_, else it will be moved to your storage and thus removed from subscriber_ids_ and not be managed by whatever mechanism works with subscriber_ids_.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using id = std::string;
std::vector<std::string> subscriber_ids_ = {"31"};

int ids = 42;

id&& connect_subscriber()
{
    auto id = std::to_string(ids++);
    {
        subscriber_ids_.push_back(std::move(id));
        return std::move(subscriber_ids_.back());
    }
}

void print() {
    int i=0;
    for(const auto& n:subscriber_ids_)
        std::cout << i++ << ":" << n << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{

    connect_subscriber();    // memory not privided
    print();

    connect_subscriber();    // memory not privided
    print();

    auto take_it = connect_subscriber();    // memory privided
    print();
}
```

Output is:

```
0:31 1:42 
0:31 1:42 2:43 
0:31 1:42 2:43 3:
```

**Output is not**:

```
0:31 1:42 
0:31 1:42 2:43 
0:31 1:42 2:43 3:44
```

Comment: Note that in the first case the last line still outputs 4 things but the fourth one is an empty string (the last entry of the vector, that was moved out of)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you aim to accomplish #2, but you can distinguish by returning a proxy object with a conversion (preferably from rvalue reference) to the type the caller should store ("capture" means something else).

That conversion can perform arbitrary actions, such as removing the object from the auto-lifetime list.

The compiler is allowed to elide copy constructor calls during a return sequence (e.g. RVO, NRVO).  But it can't elide a conversion.